# Python not summing (add) numbers, just sticking them together

Tags: python

So I just started learning how to code (completely new at this) and I decided to go with Python... So I recently am learning how to use functions to do math and I was making my own "coding" to see if I can come up with the result I want which is use functions to add x + y and give me a result but I keep getting the literal x + y and not the sum of those two numbers. eg. 1 + 1 = 11 (instead of 2)

Below is the code, can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks!~
(and yes, I am using a book but it is somehow vague on the explanations [Learn Python the Hard Way])

```
def add(a, b):
    print "adding all items"
    return a + b

fruits = raw_input("Please write the number of fruits you have \n> ")
beverages = raw_input("Please write the number of beverages you have \n> ")

all_items = add(fruits, beverages)
print all_items
```

FYI, the code the book gave me was:

```
    def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "SUBTRACTING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
print "MULTIPLYING %d * %d" % (a, b)
return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print "DIVIDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b


 print "Let's do some math with just functions!"

age = add(30, 5)
height = subtract(78, 4)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)

print "Age: %d, Height: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)

# puzzle
print "Here is a puzzle."

what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))

print "that becomes: ", what, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

Comment: it is supposed to stick in this way because what you put into `raw_input()` is a string. Check and convert it to integer

Comment: `raw_input` sends the input as string format you need to typecast it to integer, i.e. `fruits = int(raw_input("Please write the number of fruits you have \n> "))`

Comment: man that was fast answering, thanks a lot that solved my problem, i havent been taught really how to use integer (i have but it was so vague i didnt fully understand)..cheers :)

Comment: Yes, you can add a lot of different stuff in Python: lists, tuples, strings, integers, floats, anything that has the `__add__` magic method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In python (and a lot of other languages), the + operator serves a dual purpose. It can be used to get the sum of two numbers (number + number), or concatenate strings (string + string). Concatenate here means join together.

When you use `raw_input`, you get back the user's input in the form of a string. Thus, doing `fruits + beverages` invokes the latter meaning of `+`, which is string concatenation.

To treat the user's input as a number, simply use the built-in [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function:

```
all_items = add(int(fruits), int(beverages))
```

`int()` here converts both strings to integers. Those numbers are then passed to `add()`. Keep in mind that unless you implement a check to make sure that the user has inputted a number, invalid input will cause a ValueError.

Comment: thanks that helped me understand it even better

Comment: @EricAhn Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) once the waiting period is over, and best of luck.

Comment: Minor quibble: I would say the word "cast" is incorrect here, because you actually want to *convert* the value into an `int` object, not simply *cast* it. The Python language doesn't really have typecasting like some other languages do. The `int()` "function" here is actually the constructor for the `int` class (which is a built-in type in Python), which is the class of integer number values; by calling `int()` with a string argument, you pass that string into the `int` constructor and get a corresponding `int` object. Just a point of terminology -- otherwise, this answer is totally correct.

Answer (score 3):

The '+' operator can be a concatenation operator for strings, lists etc. and an addition operator for numbers. Try adding `int()` wrappers to your inputs. Also you may see the type of a variable via `type()`

Comment: thanks for the fast comment, it definitely helped

Answer (score 2):

The `raw_input` function returns a string, not a number. The `+` operator, when used on strings, concatenates them.

You need to parse the strings into numbers using `int()` or `float()` on the result.